# configure function for tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a button change when it is pressed but the `configure` function when I use it returns the error:

```
A1.config(text="X", state="disabled", relief="SUNKEN")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'
```

I also tried using `configure` instead of `config` and the response is the same:

```
    A1.configure(text="X", state="disabled", relief="SUNKEN")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'configure'
```

(for reference)
the button:

```
A1 = Button(window,text="",width=5, height=1, command=click).place(x=100, y=100)
```

the command:

```
def click():
    A1.configure(text="X", state="disabled", relief="SUNKEN")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't define a variable and place it in the same line. Try this:

```
A1 = Button(window, text="", width=5, height=1)
A1.place(x=100, y=100)
```

also `"SUNKEN"` isn't valid, either do `"sunken"` or `SUNKEN`